# Writing FileStream to Local Path and not the server

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I have the following code working successfully:

```
Protected Sub ExportExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportExcel.Click
        Dim warnings As Warning()
        Dim streamids As String()
        Dim mimeType As String
        Dim encoding As String
        Dim filenameExtension As String
        Dim fileName As String = "D:\Report" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") & ".xls"
        Dim bytes As Byte() = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("Excel", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension, streamids, warnings)

        Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        End Using
        lblMessage.Text = Functions.GetMessageConfirm("Report downloaded successfully in your D:/ at: " & Now.ToString)
    End Sub
```

This code saves the file in the web server. I want to save the file on the client machine.

Comment: Is this in any particular language, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Looks like VB>Net, tagging accordingly.

Comment: Is this for a web application? Then you cannot access to the client HD (unless your client uses IE and configure your site as a Trusted Site, and thats is not a very common situation).

Comment: This is a website. I am looking for a way to download a rdlc report on the client side as an excel.

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there, probably. You can't just save files on the client anyway. Clients are webbrowsers, and they run JavaScript.

What you can do is use the download functionality of webbrowsers, to let them download the file which you just created. To do so, put the output on the server in a directory from where it can be downloaded, then return the new URL to the client.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your response I would have to save this file in the server and then send the download link to client.

Comment: Is there a way to directly download an rdlc report to client as an excel?

Comment: How should I know? I don't even know what "rdlc" is.